# How to connect to app inside docker container inside wsl2 from Windows host?

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, wsl-2

On Windows:

I just created app via `dotnet new mvc` and created Dockerfile for that:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/App.csproj", "src/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/App.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src"
RUN dotnet build "App.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "App.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "App.dll"]
```

I then opened wsl2, went into `/mnt/d/myproject` and built built that `docker build -t app .` and started it.

I see it running

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
9e17cbwe6e4c        test1               "dotnet App.dll"    5 days ago          Up About a minute   80/tcp, 443/tcp     affectionate_goldstine
```

also there are correct logs:

```
[10:54:13 WRN] Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
[10:54:13 INF] User profile is available. Using '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
[10:54:13 INF] Now listening on: http://[::]:80
[10:54:13 INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[10:54:13 INF] Hosting environment: Production
[10:54:13 INF] Content root path: /app/
```

but I'm not sure how can I connect to it?

Comment: you have to expose port 80 by using -p option `-p 80:80`, you can reach your app at host_ip:80

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to expose port using -p

```
docker run -itd --name myapp -p 80:80 <image>
```

then you can reach your app at `host_ip:80`

Comment: Welcome glad to know it helped